# Vim finding where functions and such are declared

Tags: c, vim

In VS Code, there's a nice utility where I can right-click a keyword and it will allow me to view where that variable/function/macro/etc. is declared, defined, or used. For example, let's say in the following code:

[image: Code in Vim]

I want to `goto` the place in the file (`stdio.h`) that declares this function. Is there a simple way where I can 'follow a file/function' in vim to be able to view this information upstream?

For reference, I do have `ctags` installed and my `stdlib` is located at:

```
$ gcc --print-file-name=libc.a 
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.a
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use the *tag* operation.   If you have generated a `tags` file of the set of files you are interested in.  The `ctags` command can generate it for C and C++.

Then, in the source code, position vim's cursor on the symbol to look up and press ctrl-`]` character.

===== addendum =====

```
$ gcc -M > dir_list    # list directories which are searched    
$ vim dir_list      # edit file list to remove \ at end of line
                    # and remove the `.o` file listed
$ ctags -L dir_list *.c   # examine source files for symbols
```

Comment: thanks, I have `ctags` and when trying `ctrl-]` I get: `E426: tag not found: getchar`. How do I 'ingest' all the C library files I want?

Comment: @David542:  Create a `tags` file which includes all the header files for the program.  Or maybe *all* of the header files, which will be inconvenient to do.

Comment: hm, so then from here: `$ gcc --print-file-name=libc.a` `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.a` do you know how I'd index all those?

Comment: @David542:  I didn't test this, but you want something like the amendment (above).

Answer (score 1):

To search through included files only, use `[i`, `[d` and other commands from `:h include-search`. There's no need to generate tags for this to work. The only requirement is that your `:h 'path'` will be set properly.